# MVC Spring 3.x controller mapping and action URI (/tag1/tag1/../tag1/action)

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, spring-security, hibernate-mapping, spring-3

Hi everyone and thanks a lot for helping and excuse me for my rusty english :).
I was trying to create a  mvc website with spring 3.x , spring-security ,and .jsp pages, i can paste a lot of code here but i think it will be useless because it is a kind of logic problem on how the URI of the action and the uri of the controller works:

1)Jsp pages:
     login:    avalaible to all guests and return homeAdmin for admins with action "home" or
    homeUser : for users with the action 
    homeAdmin : provides a menu with different actions mapped with " admin/action" 
    HomeUser : provides a menu with different actions mapped with " user/action" 
    UserLIst: a page that list every users and their information in a table

2)Controller :
      guest controller: no class controller ,there are only two methods. First for mapping value={ "/, home"} and latter for "login". So everyone that try to do a request will be redirect to the login page for be able to login

```
@Controller
   public class LoginController {

   @RequestMapping(value={"/home","/"}
   (code)//if admin homeAdmin else homeUser
   return new ModelAndView("home");

   @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   (code)
   return new ModelAndView("login");
....
```

There is a requestmapping for the class with the value "/admin/" for map the first part of the Uri-action;and there are different methods with the request mapping for a specificated action , like list User.
AdminController

```
@controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

@RequestMapping(value={"/list", "/adminFilm"})
(code)
return new ModelAndView("adminFilm");
...
```

Now i do login as admin and my URL became
 `"localhost:8080/name_project/homeAdmin.jsp"`
 which is URI corresponding to URL 
`"/webapp/metainf/views/homeAdmin.jsp"` 
(generated by method InternalResuorceViewResolver into its xml page).
Pressing the button "List User" I perform an action="admin/list", now my URI is
 `"localhost:8080/name_project/admin/listUser.jsp"` 
At this point any of my action don't need to generate "admin/"  because is alredy in the path but if try to logout (j_springsecurity_Logout) my URL in the top becames from 
     `"localhost:8080/name_project/admin/listUser"`,
 to  
`"localhost:8080/name_project/admin/j_spring_Logout"`
so i get (naturally) an error for a mapping not found.
 Same problem appears for homepage request because it is mapped by LoginController and not in AdminController, so when i request it from any page that have path "/admin/home", this is not found and can't call the controller in loginController.
I could solve it forcing paths of jsp pages, but it's bad programming (and generates errors). How can i solve this problem of paths?

If problem isn't understandable, I'll try to re-write it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it the current URL in the browsers address bar is `localhost:8080/name_project/admin/listUser`. Now you click a link (or button, doesn't matter) that has the URL `j_springsecurity_Logout`. This is **relative** to the current path so you get the expected behavior: The resolved URL is `localhost:8080/name_project/admin/j_spring_Logout`.

What you need is the link's URL to be relative to the application path. That's what `<c:url />` is for. So, in case of a link, instead of

```
<a href="j_spring_Logout">
```

you write

```
<a href="<c:url value="j_spring_Logout" />">
```